# Submit form and get redirect url

Tags: c#, java, javascript

I need to submit some data on a website in-order to register a server. I need to  enter information onto a form in the first webpage and upon submitting the information, the webpage takes me to a dynamically created page (I also need to retrieve this page) where I have to enter more information in the form.

I need to accomplish this task programmatically. I can either use Java, Javscript or C#. I am familiar with the languages, but not completely sure what libraries could I use in any of the languages to achieve this task. I would really appreciate it if you guys can provide some help/hints or starting points on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many choices out there. Look for something that implements an HTTP user agent.

One Java library i use often and recommend is [Apache Commons Httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Answer (score 1):

It is completely possible to use Commons HttpClient but it might be a bit too low level for your requirements.

[HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) simulates a browser which should make it relatively easy to log in to a website, navigate around and submit a form. There is an example of submitting a form here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: :-] ask a question in a programmers forum, and you're likely to get a programmer's answer, like HttpClient. In fact my favorite tool to do this stuff is Perl's LWP::UserAgent, but Perl wasn't one of the choices. I like your idea of using a HTMLUnit, though. When i do this stuff, i first use a proxy such as [burp](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) to analyse the interaction, taking notes of what fields get sent. Then i use LWP::UserAgent or HttpClient to duplicate that.

Answer (score 0):

If the site requires javascript to be enabled and does lot of client side processing (ajax etc), then you can give [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) a try.